# $.extend not working with arrays with in objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Facing problem while changing array with in extended object in jquery.

**Example:**

```
var a = {}, b = {j: 2, arr : [{1:1}]};

$.extend(a, b);

console.log("A=" ,a);
console.log("B=" , b);

b.arr.push({2:2});

console.log("A=" , a);
console.log("B=" , b);
```

***Link:*** http://fiddle.jshell.net/GopsAB/BZu7S/1/

**Expected:**
object a should not changed while change b.

Comment: This is not occurs while using json.stringify and json.parse.

Comment: Reading [**documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) usually helps: *"The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second or subsequent object. The values are not merged. This can be seen in the example below by examining the value of banana. However, by passing true for the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged."*

Comment: *"This is not occurs while using json.stringify and json.parse."* No surprise here, since `JSON.parse` creates a new object/array from a string.

Comment: Missed the documentation, sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `deep` option to copy all the subobjects instead of sharing them:

```
$.extend(true, a, b);
```

[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BZu7S/2/)